# connect local sqlserver through in internet

Tags: sql-server, nat, port-forwarding, asp.net

Internet------> Router in my network

------->LocalMachine(Windows 2003) -->Sqlserver2005

How access sqlserver through internet via Router in local

network.

My router IP Address is =192.168.1.86; 
My local machine which is connected to the router Ip

Address is=     192.168.1.81 
At port No=1433

tell how to connect to my sqlserver. 
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2):

The 192.168.1.81 address is a local address and will not be accessible from the internet.

I would not make sql server accessible from the internet - you are just asking to be hacked.  But, if you really must...

You need an external address.  You can go to grc.com and do a shields up port scan.  It will tell you your external ip at home as well as the security holes...

You need to put rules in place on your physical firewall to allow access through that port.

You need to put rules in place on your windows firewall on the sql server machine to allow access.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to open port 1433 in your router/firewall and point it to your local machine where your SQL server is installed. On some SOHO routers this is called virtual server.

You should be aware though, this is not the best security practice to open outside access to your LAN. Better way is to make a DMZ segment.

Answer (score 1):

Everything mson said applies, but in addition you may need NAT port forwarding rules to forward the incoming connection on port 1433 to your internal IP address.  Depending on the version of SQL Server, you may need to [specifically enable TCP as a connection method](https://serverfault.com/questions/58579/cannot-connect-to-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://www.indiabroadband.net/broadband-how/10742-port-fowarding-problem-d-link-glb-802c.html)

Comment: Please refrain from just posting links, thank you :)